# How to display ArrayList Object in Thymeleaf page

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, thymeleaf

I try to display `Arraylist` object in Thmeleaf page but I got `null` for the value.
I can display the arraylist in controller on console. Is it correct the way I pass arraylist in function.

In controller

```
@RequestMapping("/searchSummon")
public String Search(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("summonsDetailType", new SummonsDetailType());
    model.addAttribute("rowType", new RowType());

    return "searchSummon";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchProcess(SummonsDetailType summonsDetailType, RowType rowType) {

    ArrayList<RowType> rowTypes2 = new ArrayList<RowType>();
    SummonsDetailType summonsDetailType2 = pdxiRes.getRequest().getSummonsDetail();

    for (RowType rowType3 : summonsDetailType2.getRow()) {
        rowTypes2.add(rowType3);
    }

    System.out.println(rowTypes2.get(0).getDistrictCode());
    return "/searchResult";
}
```

html page

```html
<tr th:each="rowType : ${rowType}">
  <td th:text="'NRIC NO: ' + ${rowType.DistrictCode}"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You never add the list to the model. The code looks really odd in other ways too, I recommend you spend some more time with the tutorials/documentation.

Comment: Add ArrayList to the model the same like you did in `Search` method.

Comment: `model.addAttribute("rowType", new RowType());` i'm suspecting this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the arraylist in model

```
model.addAttribute("rowTypes2", rowTypes2);
```